# Macro inserting zeroes

Tags: excel, vba

Any help would be much appreciated.  This excel vb script searches for X or x in a sheet named "Order sheet -SL"  and then insert specific cells values into a new sheet.  It is working well except that it’s inserting 0’s (Zero) in the new sheet insert of the actual values

Source Code:

```
Sub SOLIMPORT2(worksheetname As String)
    Dim Order As Worksheet
    Dim SolomonImport As Worksheet

    Set Order = Worksheets("Order sheet -SL")
    Set SolomonImport = Worksheets(worksheetname)


    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    i = 8
    j = 3




    Do
        If Order.Cells(i, 6) = "x" Or Order.Cells(i, 6) = "X" Then
            SolomonImport.Range("A1") = "LEVEL0"
            SolomonImport.Range("B1") = "SO #:"
            SolomonImport.Range("C1") = "PSO"
            SolomonImport.Range("A3") = "LEVEL1"
            SolomonImport.Cells(j, 2) = Order.Cells(i, 11)
            SolomonImport.Cells(j, 3) = Order.Cells(i, 13)
            'Range("I10").Value = Range("F10").Value

            SolomonImport.Cells(j, 4) = Order.Cells(i, 14)
            SolomonImport.Cells(j, 5) = Order.Cells(i, 15)
            'SolomonImport.Cells(j, 31) = Order.Range("F1")
            'SolomonImport.Cells(j, 32) = "TC-50"
            'SolomonImport.Cells(j, 3) = Order.Cells(i, 11)
            'SolomonImport.Cells(j, 5) = "0"
            'SolomonImport.Cells(j, 13) = "0"
            'SolomonImport.Cells(j, 37) = Order.Cells(i, 8)
            'SolomonImport.Cells(j, 38) = Order.Cells(i, 10)

            j = j + 1
        End If

        i = i + 1

        If Order.Range("A" & Trim(Str(i))) = "SHEET TAB Z" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Example:
**Ordered Sheet –SL tab contained source data:**

1. ```
      RELEASE    PART #      QUANTITY         UNIT COST       EXTENDED COST

      x          MX418 S/C     1              147.9           147.9
      x          MX418 D/C     4              178.5           714
      x          MX418 S/C     2              147.9       295.8
   ```

**The new sheet and the output:**

The new sheet: The yellow highlighted cells above are showing as 0 below.  The unite Cost cells contained this formula (=A!L9) and the Extended Cost cells formula is Quantity multiply by Unit Cost.

```
MX418 S/C   1   0   1

MX418 D/C   4   0   0

MX418 S/C   2   0   0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is just copying the formulas rather than the values from the original sheet.

Try adding `.value` at the end of each of the `order.cells(x,y)`'s.

i.e. `SolomonImport.Cells(j, 4) = Order.Cells(i, 14).value`

Comment: Thank you for your help Tim. After adding the ".value" to the script. It still copying the formulas rather than the values from the original sheet.

Comment: just to confirm you script should now look like this:

`SolomonImport.Range("A1") = "LEVEL0"

SolomonImport.Range("B1") = "SO #:"

SolomonImport.Range("C1") = "PSO"

SolomonImport.Range("A3") = "LEVEL1"

SolomonImport.Cells(j, 2) = Order.Cells(i, 11).value

SolomonImport.Cells(j, 3) = Order.Cells(i, 13).value

SolomonImport.Cells(j, 4) = Order.Cells(i, 14).value

SolomonImport.Cells(j, 5) = Order.Cells(i, 15).value`

Comment: Yes, I added ".value" at the end of each of the order.cells(x,y)'s.